# Refused to execute inline script in Manifest V3 extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, inline-scripting

I'm building a Chrome extension using Manifest V3, and I'm trying to execute an inline script using chrome.scripting.executeScript(). However, I keep getting the error message "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive".

I understand that Manifest V3 has stricter security requirements than previous versions, and I've tried modifying my content_security_policy_extension_pages and web_accessible_resources directives to allow for inline scripts and other potentially unsafe functions, but I'm still getting the same error message.

Here's my current manifest file:

```
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"name": "***",
"description": "**",
"version": "1.0",
"icons": {
    "123": "icon.png"
},
"action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "scripting",
    "tabs",
    "cookies",
    "webNavigation"
],
"host_permissions": [
    "*://*.test.com/*",
    "*://.test.com/*"
],
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*.test.com/*"],
    "js": ["popup.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
}],
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["*"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
    }
  ]
```

}

And here's the code I'm trying to execute in background:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        setInterval(async function () {
            var response = await fetch('https://test.com/test.php');
            const data = await response.text();
            console.log(data);

            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tabId },
                func: (data) => {
                    // Use the downloaded script code here
                    const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
                    scriptElement.textContent = data;
                    document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
                },
                args: [data]
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Is there anything else I can try to allow the execution of inline scripts in my extension? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto but there are those who do this in V2, can't I do it in V3?